# Angular using promise with generics inside promise

Tags: javascript, angular, promise

I need to interlace promises in my app:

```
  protected scroll<T>(path: string, pageSize: number, filter: string, data: T[]): Promise<T[]> {    
            let promise = new Promise<T[]>(function(resolve, reject) {
                this.httpClient
                    .get<T[]>(this.appConfigService.buildApiUrl(path), { params })
                    .toPromise<T[]>()
                    .then(result => {
                        if (result) {
                            resolve(data.concat(result));
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(function(e) {
                        reject(e);
                    });
            });

            return promise;
        }
```

My problem is that I receive following message:
'Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments'

How would I solve this?

UPDATE:

I should not have removed the if condition from the example:

```
  if (!filter) {
            const params = new HttpParams()
                .set('searchText', '')
                .set('skip', data.length.toString())
                .set('take', pageSize.toString());

            const promise = new Promise<T[]>((resolve, reject) => {
                this.httpClient
                    .get<T>(this.appConfigService.buildApiUrl(path), { params })
                    .toPromise<any>()
                    .then(result => {
                        if (result) {
                            resolve(data.concat(result));
                        }
                        resolve(data);
                    })
                    .catch(e => reject(e));
            });

            return promise;
        }
        // also returning a promise
        return this.filter<T>(data, pageSize, filter, path);
```

Comment: is it the toPromise() call that is causing it?

Comment: What line/statement is the error pointing to?

Comment: You use `function(resolve, reject) {...}` while addressing `this.httpClient`, but I don't see a `bind()`. I suggest you use arrow syntax: `new Promise<T[]>((resolve, reject) => {...})`.

Comment: The update doesn't fundamentally change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems there.

1. The error message is because you're using `<T[]>` on `get` and `toPromise`, which aren't generic functions. Just apply the type `T` to `result` in the `then` handler.
2. You're falling into the promise creation antipattern. You **already** have a promise (from `this.httpClient`), so you don't need `new Promise`.
3. You're using a traditional function for your `new Promise` callback, but then using `this` within it as though it were still referring to your class instance. If you were going to keep the `new Promise`, you'd want an arrow function instead, so it closes over `this`.

Instead (see `***` comments):

```
protected scroll<T>(path: string, pageSize: number, filter: string, data: T[]): Promise<T[]> {    
    // *** Return the result of calling `then` on the promise from `toPromise`
    return this.httpClient
        // *** Don't use <T[]> on `get` and `toPromise`
        .get(this.appConfigService.buildApiUrl(path), { params })
        .toPromise()
        .then((result: T) => { // *** <== Note the `T`
            // *** If it's really possible that `result` will be falsy and you don't want that
            // to be valid, you can do this:
            if (!result) {
                throw new Error("appropriate error here");
            }
            return data.concat(result);
        });
}
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=15&ssc=1&pln=5&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECiAeYC2AHEBTaBvAUNf0KATgJYBuYALpgBaWUoDCIJ6AdpQFzRhsCeAbmgB6YdABUk6ACkArhErRKAe2gBrdOhRKamNGD4BzIstlsAJtBpgUKPngLFyVTDabK2AMxKGAyuiIyEmB0bl5BETFJcRl5RRV1TW1KXUJwIxMzS2tbewd8YmVqYGpLCGATEBAAHgAVAD4AChQqGm4FUjZDABpCMEN0XxIAL1DoNlkkACMA3u8QaiJ2yk6e6HMqMG5agG0AXQBKbgAFEyQSCHQ6-frsAmh8+8iJKQAldEpZIjYdTCJ0CCyBbQZSeaDAMBVEhdaAAAxS7FhIJ+CMIZwumE8ZzhKlOynOl1hj3u-0+3x0FwAdHQGMxWBxiU98KIXjEACIeADkinkmGue1uHjhA0oSN4lnhyjxBPQRKZTMpIsaKSpbkYHm8fgCQRClKmshIIHMAEEUCQAKpEEDNVoHXpYPpEZAwAC+B0ZCtx6MujXd8qelIRbEajX+gIW2wO0AAvLdcP7-SzotAAJJgkiUTkwf6QkB8QjKKAkKYYHRUOFhoGi6AAd0NIGgM2gnkhEHz4ugfFM6y5ihrvHi1koHoTLISTYoLHMvS7snBvB7FIgnBH-pIYMaAEJKwso-GEweUiYa+N0CfYEQTERGgAiNwmJwuaABK9WALoG8HASr+Uun9M0kvh+HdKG-A98DdMCCD-P8gA)

---

> UPDATE:
>
> I should not have removed the if condition from the example:

It doesn't matter, just put the body of the above into the `if` block:

```
protected scroll<T>(path: string, pageSize: number, filter: string, data: T[]): Promise<T[]> {    
    if (!filter) {
        const params = new HttpParams()
           .set('searchText', '')
           .set('skip', data.length.toString())
           .set('take', pageSize.toString());

        return this.httpClient
            // *** Don't use <T[]> on `get` and `toPromise`
            .get(this.appConfigService.buildApiUrl(path), { params })
            .toPromise()
            .then((result: T) => { // *** <== Note the `T`
                // *** If it's really possible that `result` will be falsy and you don't want that
                // to be valid, you can do this:
                if (!result) {
                    throw new Error("appropriate error here");
                }
                return data.concat(result);
            });
    }
    return this.filter<T>(data, pageSize, filter, path);
}
```

Comment: 1 -> I need to specify T[] in order to apply concat on the result. 2. -> I don't see how you want to be able to fetch the result and apply concatting without using a .then() block.

Comment: @yBother - 1. No, you don't, see the type I applied to `result` (I should have called that out). 2. Oops, missed the concat, fixed. BTW, your update to the question doesn't fundamentally change anything.